# Is there any way to use prototype cells in UIViewController other than UITableViewController?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, xib

I made my tableView as a subview of UIViewController , and in storyboard , i add prototype cells to this scene . but it seems that the design of cells in storyboard is not working , seems prototype cells works only for UITableViewController?

here is my storyboard design which i use a tableView as ViewController's subview , and add two prototype cells in it (pink and blue cell)
[image]

and here are my tableView codes:

```
@implementation SubViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    [self.tableView registerClass:[TableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"TableViewCell"];
    [self.tableView registerClass:[ATableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"ATableViewCell"];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        TableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        return cell;
    }
    else
    {
        ATableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ATableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        return cell;
    }
}
```

and when i run my code ,i expect there will be a blue and pink cell , but in fact , the tableView will only got two blank cell (seems the design in storyboard not working)
[image]

Comment: What is the error that you are getting. Can you add some code. It should work if you have set source and delegate properly.

Comment: @kapsym thx , i've just post my storyboard design and code , anything wrong ?

Comment: Can you describe what you expect to happen, _and_ what is actually happening? What does “doesn’t work” mean in this context?

Comment: [self.tableView registerClass:[TableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"TableViewCell"];
    [self.tableView registerClass:[ATableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"ATableViewCell"]; is not required in prototype cell in storyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are designing with the Storyboard,You dont need the below lines

```
[self.tableView registerClass:[TableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"TableViewCell"];
[self.tableView registerClass:[ATableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"ATableViewCell"];
```

Instead of that you need to set identifier for cell in the storyboard as in the below image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You want to check a few things to make sure your table view is wired up and knows to look for the cells in the `SubViewController` class.

1. Make sure the UITableView has its outlet set to something you can reference in code. `self.tableView` isn’t automatically connected unless you are using a UITableViewController subclass.
2. Make sure your table view has the `SubViewController` class connected as it’s data source and delegate. You can do this in code, or by dragging in interface builder. Try adding this to your `viewDidLoad` method: `self.tableView.dataSource = self;`
3. You probably want to set up your cells to use string identifiers in the inspector panel of Interface Builder. Then, in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, dequeue your cells using that identifier, *instead* of registering by class name.

As an aside, you can also use prototype cells with UICollectionView but the API and storyboard setup are very similar, and the same steps apply.

Comment: thanks @Moshe, seems the problem is that i called registerClass for prototype cells , when i remove these calls , the cell display well